# How to disconnect Bluetooth LE connection in UWP

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have written a UWP application that advertise a GATT service. I want to know how can i disconnect the clients that connect to my GATT service?
I can find the connected devices using `DeviceInformation` class, but calling `Dispose` methods of `Session` and `BluetoothLEDevice` objects does not have any effect.

```
string filter = BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromConnectionStatus(BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected);
        DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(filter);

        foreach (DeviceInformation d in devices)
        {
            BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(d.Id);
            var gattServices = await device.GetGattServicesAsync();
            foreach (var service in gattServices.Services)
            {
                if (service.Session.SessionStatus == GattSessionStatus.Active)
                    service.Session.Dispose();

                service.Dispose();
            }
            device.Dispose();
        }
```

Is there any other way to disconnect the bluetooth connection of client devices?

Comment: According to the [Connecting to the device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client#connecting-to-the-device) section:
 On the other hand, disposing of all references to a BluetoothLEDevice object for a device (and if no other app on the system has a reference to the device) will trigger an automatic disconnect after a small timeout period.

Your code  `service.Dispose();` should work for disconnect, but you may need a small timeout period waiting.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Thanks, The Connecting to the device section is for GATT Client, and certainly disposing of BluetoothLEDevice object cause disconnecting of Client, but i want to disconnect the connection from the server side (GATT Server side)